# The function of adding a recipe to the database favorites does not work

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a problem in the application, I want to make a function to add a recipe to my favorites, but there is a problem, everything seems to look fine, but when I click on the save button, I first compare the current icon with two icons selected and not selected, if selected, I delete a recipe from my favorite firebase database, and if it’s not selected, I add it, but there is a problem when I press my if else system for some reason starts in a loop and even the button seems to be pressed by itself I don’t know why this happens, can you please help, and i use RecyclerView.

My Recipe Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/recipeImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:maxHeight="260dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:transitionName="courseImage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recipeTitle"
                android:layout_width="223dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                android:text="1234567890123456"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="52dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                    android:text="By"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                    android:text="Username"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time_svgrepo_com" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                    android:text="time"

                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
                android:layout_width="31dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/save" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Adapter:

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder> {
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    DatabaseReference mRef2;
    DatabaseReference mRef3;
    DatabaseReference mRef4;
    Context context;
    public List<Recipe> recipes;

    public RecipeAdapter(Context context, List<Recipe> courses) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recipes = courses;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View recipeItems = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item, parent, false);
        return new RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder(recipeItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecipeViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        mRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("count");
        mRef4 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("count2").child(mUser.getUid());
        mRef3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("favorite").child(mUser.getUid());

        //Listener for favorite Btn
        holder.saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mRef4.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
                        try {
                            if (holder.saveBtn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.save).getConstantState())) {
                                System.out.println("g");
                                mRef3.child(recipes.get(position).id).setValue("");
                                mRef4.setValue(Integer.parseInt(snapshot1.getValue().toString()) + 1);
                                holder.saveBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save2);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("b");
                                mRef3.child(recipes.get(position).id).removeValue();
                                holder.saveBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save);
                            }
                            return;
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        mRef4.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
                System.out.println(snapshot1.getValue().toString());
                mRef3.child(recipes.get(position).id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.getValue() == null) {

                        } else {
                            holder.saveBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save2);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

       
        
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecipePage.class);

                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                        (Activity) context,
                        new Pair<View, String>(holder.recipeImage, "recipeImage")
                );
                intent.putExtra("recipeImage", recipes.get(position).getPhotoLink());
                intent.putExtra("recipeTitle", recipes.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("recipeCookTime", recipes.get(position).getCookTime());
                intent.putExtra("recipeServes", recipes.get(position).getServes());
                intent.putExtra("recipePrepTime", recipes.get(position).getPrepTime());
                intent.putExtra("recipeAccess", recipes.get(position).getAccess());
                intent.putExtra("recipeDesc", recipes.get(position).getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("recipeIngr", recipes.get(position).getIngredients());
                intent.putExtra("recipeDire", recipes.get(position).getDirections());
                context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recipes.size();
    }

    public static final class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView recipeImage, saveBtn;
        TextView username, time, title;

        public RecipeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            saveBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
            recipeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeImage);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            username.setPaintFlags(username.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipeTitle);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable data-bindng for model class `Recipe` and your code would be instantly less dramatic - also the numbered variables do not support the readability... and "does not work" is not an error description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this sort of code:

```
mRef4.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
        try {
            if (holder.saveBtn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.save).getConstantState())) {
                System.out.println("g");
                mRef3.child(recipes.get(position).id).setValue("");
                mRef4.setValue(Integer.parseInt(snapshot1.getValue().toString()) + 1);
                holder.saveBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("b");
                mRef3.child(recipes.get(position).id).removeValue();
                holder.saveBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save);
            }
            return;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

You're adding a value listener to `mRef4`, which means that your `onDataChange` gets called immediately for the current value of `mRef4` and then **every time `mRef4` is modified tooSince you modify `mRef4` inside `onDataChange`, you're causing an infinite loop.

Most likely you want to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`:

```
    // 
mRef4.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
        try {
            if (holder.saveBtn.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.save).getConstantState())) {
                System.out.println("g");
                mRef3.child(recipes.get(position).id).setValue("");
                mRef4.setValue(Integer.parseInt(snapshot1.getValue().toString()) + 1);
                holder.saveBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("b");
                mRef3.child(recipes.get(position).id).removeValue();
                holder.saveBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save);
            }
            return;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw RuntimeError(e); //  never ignore errors
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
    }
});
```

You might have more such instances in your code, so check for any `addValueEventListener` and wonder if you indeed want to listen for updates or only want to get the value once.